# ASP.NET MVC client-side e-mail validation doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, regex, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

In my registration form I want to put some client-side validations with MVC regular expressions, but it doesn't work... Here is part of model's code

```
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address*")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

But the message don't want to appear anyway... What is wrong here?

EDIT

In my View I have this

```
            <div>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
            </div>
            </div>
```

And I've also include jQuery libraries in my layout

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    @RenderSection("Head")
</head>
```

Comment: Just a little side note. Check out the NuGet package DataAnnotationsExtensions. It has a Email DataAnnotation that you could use :) http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Comment: Please consider replacing your regex-based email validation with something more robust, as it fails with too many legit addresses, including `foo+bar@test.com`, `foo@bar.museum` and doesn't fail when it should, as with `foo..x@test.com`. I suggest you to use **[EmailVerify.NET](http://emailverify.net)**, a strong .NET [email validation](http://emailverify.net) component you can easily integrate with your ASP.NET MVC project. Disclaimer: I am the lead developer of EmailVerify.NET.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've finally figured it out...
Replacing Required attribute after RegularExpression attribute solved the problem)))

Instead this

```
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address*")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

now I have

```
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
        [Required]

        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email address*")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
```

And it now works perfectly!

Comment: This sounds like you are relying on an order to validation attributes. The message for the regex validation will only appear if (a) the field has a value and (b) that value does not conform to the regex pattern. If the field is empty then you'll get the `Required` attribute validation message until a value is entered.

Answer (score 3):

You also need

1.`@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)` in the view where you want the message to appear

2.Include the JavaScript files required for client side validation. If you are using unobtrusive validation then this will be

```
jQuery, 
jQuery validate, 
jQuery validate unobtrusive
```

in that order.

Comment: if you inspect the DOM, can you see `data-val-regex-pattern="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"` on the email input?

Comment: No, I can't see it with FIrebug... But I don'w know why... There is no data-val-regex-pattern attribute anywhere.